# How do you compile and serve a JAR with another JAR dependency (without anything but command line and a MANIFEST)?

Tags: java, jar, compilation, manifest

I have a program in a root folder `com`. Beneath that, are all of the source .java files, several of which reference a single library (JavaTuples) JAR found in `lib` folder at the same level as `com` (see directory structure below).

**GOAL:** I am wanting to compile my program, JAR it with a MANIFEST, and be able to run all from the command line.

The furthest I've gotten was running the program, and at the first use of JavaTuples within the program, I get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/javatuples/Pair` caused by `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.javatuples.Pair`. When I'm running this inside IntelliJ, I can successfully get through the whole program. What do I need to do?

*NOTE* - I am purposefully not posting my current manifest or commands because I have iterated through at least a dozen version of each, and I just want a straight answer not clouded by my incorrect manifest and commands.

```
.
├── com
|   └── directoryA
|        └── moreDirectories (of .java)
├── lib
|   └── javatuples-1.2.jar
|
├── META-INF
|   └── MANIFEST.MF
|
├── target (empty)
```

Comment: When you run from command line, you have to put the other jar in the classpath.

Comment: When I compile, I include the lib JAR file, and I've also included it in the CP in the MANIFEST file with respect to the directory I run the program from.

Comment: Are you working with any jar packaging extension, such as maven-assembly-plugin? If so, you should include your POM in the question. Straight Java doesn't allow referring to libraries within the same jar. You should include the manifest in your question.

Comment: That answers my question then - I'm not using Maven, so I'll just remove the package and handle the tuples with arrays instead. Thanks for the help!

Comment: the manifest file also allows declaring which jar files to include (when using `java -jar` or double-click on some OS): [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: You don't need to remove use of the library. All you need to do is make sure that the library is somewhere on the machine. The classpath allows adding a reference to a library that is *not* in the jar. You simply can't do it with a single jar in basic Java.